# Simple windows batch file that will copy a file to a folder, and create a sub-folder with timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file at:

```
c:\source\hello.txt
```

That I want to backup as I modify it often, to here:

```
c:\backups\source\????\hello.txt
```

How can I create such a .bat file to do this?

I want the script to somehow create a sub-folder with the current date and time, so that when I view the folders it will be ordered so I can get the latest or go back in time easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a main idea from [here](http://www.jasonprahl.com/?p=1631):

```
@echo off
set hh=%time:~-11,2%
set /a hh=%hh%+100
set hh=%hh:~1%
set dateseed=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%hh%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

if not exist "c:\backups\source\%dateseed%" mkdir "c:\backups\source\%dateseed%"
cd "c:\backups\source\%dateseed%"
copy "c:\source\hello.txt" .
```

It will create a folder named yyyymmdd_hhmmss (hh in 24-hours format).

You can also check `copy /?` for further options.

If you're working with files or folders other than on `C:` make sure you add a line to change to that drive before attempting to make a folder or change dir into one.